# MultiMap in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, multimap

I would like to have a multimap or ListMultiMap in flutter, since I require multiple values with same key, when I use dart's quiver collection as per the dart document, MultiMap showing error, saying no such method. Can anyone help me please.
imported quiver collection and then tried using Multimap class

```
import 'package:quiver/collection.dart';
```

https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.collection/Multimap-class.html

tried using Multimap as per above documentation, but showing error

```
Multimap<String, String> multimap = new MultiMap<String,String>();
```

Comment: Please update the question showing the code that doesn't work

Comment: I have updated the question, since it is factory method, i need to call in some other way it seems, can anyone help in that?

Comment: `Multimap` is an abstract class, but has a factory constructor that returns a `ListMultimap` - one of its concrete sub-classes. This is a nice Dart convenience - the regular Dart abstract map does the same trick returning a `LinkedHashmap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have a typo. Note that you are saying `new MultiMap` with the M of map capitalized. (Note that the `new` keyword isn't needed and should be dropped.)

The following works as expected:

```
import 'package:quiver/collection.dart';

void main() {
  var myMap = Multimap<String, String>();
  myMap.add('a', 'a1');
  myMap.add('a', 'a2');
  myMap.forEach((key, value) => print('[$key->$value]'));
}
```

and prints:

```
[a->a1]
[a->a2]
```

Comment: I need to put this map in a listview with key as header and items with same key as each row and repeat this for whole item. I want to put what I have done here, but here it is not allowing because of space constraints. Can you please help?

Comment: Surely that's a new question. If this answer was useful, accept it. Then ask your new question.

Comment: I have already accepted and will definitely ask a new question, thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58586562/multilistmap-items-display-in-a-listview-in-flutter here is the link for new question

Comment: I'll take a look at the new question. When you accept an answer it should end up with a green check mark against it. Please be sure to always accept the most useful answer.

Comment: I think that you mentioned I dont know exactly, I have upvoted the answer which you have put.